# Generate ids based on text present in attributes of nodes in xml datatype in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table in sql server which has a column field of XML type. This column contains  some XML files, not all files are same. There is one type of XML which contains data like:

```
<Package>
<InputNumber description="[1] What is the height of the Box."> 
<value/> </InputNumber>
<InputNumber description="[2] What is the width of the Box."> 
<value/> </InputNumber>
<InputNumber description="[3] What is the depth of the Box."> 
<value/> </InputNumber>
<InputNumber description="(1-3) Area of the box."> 
<value/> </InputNumber>
<InputNumber description="[4] What is the weight of the Box."> 
<value/> </InputNumber>
<InputNumber description="[5] Number of boxes."> 
<value/> </InputNumber>
<InputNumber description="(4-5) Total weight of all the boxes."> 
<value/> </InputNumber>
</Package>
```

I am fetching the description and value as:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[SPMethod]
(   
    @id int,

 )
As
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
@sql=N'SELECT tbl.Id' + @CRLF +
N', c.value(''../@description'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [description]' + @CRLF +
    N', Value = c.value(''.'', ''VARCHAR(max)'')' + @CRLF +
    N'FROM Table AS tbl' + @CRLF +
    N'CROSS APPLY tbl.ColXML.nodes(''/Package[1]/InputNumber/Value]'') AS t(c)' + @CRLF +
    N'where id=@id';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N' @id int',@id;
```

Now, I want to have some IDs for each row based on description. So, the IDs I want are 1,2,3,1-3,4,5,1-6 which are present in the description strings.
The output should look like:

- description-----------------------------value------------ID
- [1] What is the height of the Box. -----Null----------[1]
- [2] What is the width of the Box. ------Null----------[2]
- [3] What is the depth of the Box. ------Null  --------[3]
- (1-3) Area of the box.  ----------------Null --------(1-3)

Comment: Why is statement set up to be dynamic, when there's nothing dynamic about it? (Your use of `@CRLF` seems like it's come from an answer I've given as well, as I don't see anyone else that using that style for adding carriage returns and line breaks to dynamic statement unless it's come from one of mine.) What are you expected results here? Why are some ID's exclosed in brakcets (`[]`) and other parentheses (`()`)? Seems like the data model is the *real* problem here.

Comment: This sql is assigned to a variable inside a stored procedure.

Comment: This is an existing database, I am not planning to add any attribute to this to maintain the consistency throughout, So I thought of taking the values from description attribute for IDs.

Comment: My expected output is a table with rows containing description, value and ID

Comment: You haven't addressed any of the questions in my comment here.

Comment: I did not know the use of @crlf is for dynamic sql, I thought it is just a line break

Comment: `@CRLF` isn't for dynamic SQL, it's the fact you're defining a statement in a literal `nvarchar` that suggest it's a "dynamic" statement. The reason I say "dynamic", however, is because there is *nothing* dynamic about the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212104/discussion-between-richa-verma-and-larnu).

Comment: There is no need to discuss this is chat, [edit] your question, address the questions I had. *That* is why this isn't getting any answers.

Answer (score -1):

Please don't format dynamic SQL like that.  TSQL supports multi-line string literals.

So this:

```
N'SELECT tbl.Id' + @CRLF +
N', c.value(''../@description'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [description]' + @CRLF +
    N', Value = c.value(''.'', ''VARCHAR(max)'')' + @CRLF +
    N'FROM Table AS tbl' + @CRLF +
    N'CROSS APPLY tbl.ColXML.nodes(''/Package[1]/InputNumber/Value]'') AS t(c)' + @CRLF +
    N'where id=10';
```

should simply be

```
N'SELECT tbl.Id
       , c.value(''../@description'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [description]
       , Value = c.value(''.'', ''VARCHAR(max)'')
FROM Table AS tbl
CROSS APPLY tbl.ColXML.nodes(''/Package[1]/InputNumber/Value]'') AS t(c)
where id=10';
```

Comment: oh ok, i will be updating the stored procedure. I was not aware of it